# Login Loop Issue Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: login, 18.04

Note: I'm asking separately as I couldn't find anything specific to 18.04.

I am unable to login into my account. The screen goes to black after entering the password for user and returns to the login screen. The best I can tell, the issue is caused because .gvfs and .dbus file in the `/user/home/` directory are owned by root. How do I get out of this mess?

[image: Image of syslog after failed login(Ubuntu)]
<sup>**syslog after failed login(Ubuntu)**</sup>
[image: Image of syslog after failed login(Ubuntu Wayland)]
<sup>**syslog after failed login(Ubuntu Wayland)**</sup>

Comment: What leads you to the conclusion that those files are the culprit?

Comment: Because those are the two files are owned by root in my user home directory. As I understand, all files in the user home must be owned by the user and not root, yeah?

Comment: No, those files are properly owned by root. While they might be related to your crash, it's unlikely. Note the exact time of a failed login, then review /var/log/syslog for that time. Edit your question to add anything suspicious you find there.

Comment: I'm really no expert, but the thing that caught my eye was the following:
`/usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[1327]: Unable to run session `

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the full, complete 5 lines before and after that message! Attaching a photo is fine (since you can't get to GUI) as long as the log entries are readable.